# Nested repeater with button

Tags: asp.net, repeater

in my page I have two nested repeaters as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptStanze" OnItemDataBound="rptStanze_ItemDataBound">       
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <li class="datatable-item">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="hypGetDetails" Text="Get Details" OnCommand="GetObjectDetails" />
                <div class="col2">DATE</div>
                <div class="col3">VISITORS</div>
            </li>      
            <li>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDetails" OnItemDataBound="rptDetails_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="subitem">
                            <div class="col2"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDetTitle" /></div>
                            <div class="col3"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDetViews" /></div>
                            <div class="col4"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDetComments" /></div>
                        </div>                        
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the first, I have a **LinkButton** with a method that fills the nested repeater. Concerning the bounding of data I've no problems, but I dunno how to get the correct nested repeater to fill. In the **GetObjectDetails** method how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Command` handler, one of the parameters is the button that sent the request, commonly referred to as the "sender". Using that, you just need to find the container of the button that was clicked and then find the repeater within that container.

Here is a C# example:

```
protected void GetObjectDetails(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    LinkButton hypGetDetails = (LinkButton)sender;
    RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)hypGetDetails.NamingContainer;
    Repeater rptDetails = (Repeater)ri.FindControl("rptDetails");
}
```